# This proof of the first fundamental theorem of calculus is so confusing

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

**From my book**

> 4. The fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
>    If $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$, let $c \in[a, b]$ and $F(x)=\int_{c}^{x} f(t) d t$ if $x \in[a, b]$ then and $F^{\prime}(x)=\frac{d}{d x} \int_{c}^{x} f(t) d t=\frac{d}{d x}[F(x)-F(c)]=F^{\prime}(x)=f(x)$

I understand that the first fundamental theorem of calculus deals with the derivative of anti-derivative, in other way, it tries to answer the question of "what is the derivative of an antiderivative?".

But in the proof above he differentiated $F(x)$ but in the end he arrived to also $F'(x) $ which he assumed to be $f(x)$ so if he put at the end $F'(x) $ is $f(x) $ why he waited to the end? why he didn't put it at the beginning of the proof? why the proof in the first place?

So my question would be:

**Is the proof above incorrect or I'm misunderstanding it?**[image]

Comment: Is something missing between _then_ and _and_? If so, please edit it in.

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: The proof _should_ begin$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_c^xf(t)dt=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_c^{x+h}f(t)dt-\int_c^xf(t)dt}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\int_x^{x+h}f(t)dt,$$then motivate the last expression being $f(x)$ by [explaining why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals) for all $h\ne0$ some $\xi_h\in[0,\,1]$ satsifies $\frac1h\int_x^{x+h}f(t)dt=f(x+\xi_hh)$.

Comment: This seems to be transcribed poorly. I’d like to see a picture of this page in the book. Edit: Thanks for posting the picture; I see it’s transcribed correctly. Have you considered reading a different book?

Comment: I think the "and" after "then" is a typo in the book, look in the picture above, and this is my professor's book (not a famous book)

Comment: @littleO I've seen the proof in Wikipedia and other internet sites that's why I can, sort of, "know" that the proof in the book above is not correct (in my opinion), so do you see the proof in the book as correct?If so how?

Comment: What is given in the book is not the proof but just the theorem.

Comment: To me it appears that the proof (if it’s intended to be a proof) is bogus. It seems to define $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$. At this point we don’t yet know that $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$. The proof then seems to assert that $\int_a^x f(t) \, dt = F(x) - F(a)$. But how is that step justified if we don’t yet know that $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$? I think it doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @littleO that's what I thought

Comment: @kmitov oh dear.. you might be right .. I think it makes more sense if it was the statement. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's given in the book is not a theorem: To supplement littleO's comment, integrability of $f$ does not guarantee $F'(x) = f(x)$.